# Adding a new entity to coredata - can I still use lightweight migration?

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, core-data

I have an existing core data set and I want to add an entity to it. I'm a little confused over whether I can use lightweight migration after adding a new entity to transition existing users to the new model.

The current modal is (just showing entities):

```
Story 1toMany-> Sentences
```

I need:

```
Story 1toMany-> Sentences 1toMany-> Media
```

Can I use the lightweight migration tool to do this?

I've read in the [documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/cocoa/conceptual/CoreDataVersioning/Articles/vmLightweightMigration.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40004399-CH4-SW1):

> For Core Data to be able to generate an inferred mapping model,
>   changes must fit an obvious migration pattern, for example:
>
> Simple addition of a new attribute Removal of an attribute A
>   non-optional attribute becoming optional An optional attribute
>   becoming non-optional, and defining a default value Renaming an entity
>   or property

But [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7964574/459116) seems to suggest lightweight migration will still work with the addition of an entity. Since the new media entity is optional I can't see how it would practically be a problem.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Check the core data video "Mastering core data" from wwdc 2010. They talk about migration for your specific case. Long story short: yes, you can use lightweight migration. Just pass the options dictionary when initializing the NSPersistentStoreCoordinator instance:

```
NSDictionary *dictionary=[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjects:@[ [NSNumber numberWithBool:YES], [NSNumber numberWithBool:YES]] forKeys:@[ NSMigratePersistentStoresAutomaticallyOption, NSInferMappingModelAutomaticallyOption]];
```

Comment: MIgration starts from 45:42 in the video.

Answer (score 9):

Yes, you will likely be able to use lightweight migration. In my experience, I've found you'll want to Add Model Version... under the Editor menu *before* you make changes to your CoreData Model. This way there is a before and after scenario to map. Then, you'll need to set the new model as the current model. (You can now add an entity to the Core Data model. Be sure that you are working on the correct model.)

Finally, you need to make sure you pass options for initializing the PersistentStoreCoordinator.

```
NSError *error = nil;
_persistentStoreCoordinator = [[NSPersistentStoreCoordinator alloc] initWithManagedObjectModel:[self managedObjectModel]];
NSDictionary *options = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:[NSNumber numberWithBool: YES],NSMigratePersistentStoresAutomaticallyOption,[NSNumber numberWithBool:YES],NSInferMappingModelAutomaticallyOption, nil];
if (![_persistentStoreCoordinator addPersistentStoreWithType:NSSQLiteStoreType configuration:nil URL:storeURL options:options error:&error]) {...
```